# Set mediators variables with a file

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

It's possible to set a variable of mediator configuration field with a file? I just don't want to hard code the timeout field of a cache mediator, it is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we are not able to pass an expression to timeout value. [1] only expects an integer to be provided not an expression.

[1]-https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/master/components/mediation-ui/mediators-ui/org.wso2.carbon.mediator.cache.ui/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/mediator/cache/ui/CacheMediator.java#L419

Comment: So there is no way of doing that in wso2?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible to achieve with the current implementation of the cache mediator. If you follow the code change in message store mediator[1] you can observe that the mediator code was modified so that it could provide the ability to get a dynamic value. With the cache mediator implementation, it expects only a value for the timeout but not a variable.

[1]-https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/pull/816/files

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file stored in the registry like this, but I'm not sure if it's possible to change the cache timeout using a variable.

```
<property name="xmlFile" expression="get-property('registry','gov:/test.xml')" scope="default" type="OM"></property>

<log level="custom">
    <property name="Book_Name" expression="$ctx:xmlFile//book"></property>
</log>
```

Ref: https://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2015/09/wso2-esb-how-to-read-value-from-xml.html

Comment: Open the ref link :)

Comment: I'm getting the following error "Unexpected EOF in prolog" with the same code as the link show, can you help me with that?